# SSL Certificate Breaking the Site Style Sheets - Looking for a fix

Tags: ssl, stylesheets

I've inherited an old version of an expression engine website using version 2.10.1. The site is not displaying on https:// and when I am testing the stylesheets are broken. I've been informed that the agency who designed the site a few years tried to fix it and was unable to ( which blew my mind.

So, can anyone advise me how to get the https://www.mysite.com version working please.

Thank you in advance...
Naomi

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: @BenoitL I removed the domain to protect the client. Old versions of EE means old versions of PHP, meaning vulnerabilities. Best not to advertise.

Comment: I completely understand ;).. Anyway jrothafer got your answer!..

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to access your templates fix this issue. Log in to your control panel, and visit:

`Design -> Templates -> Template Manager`

Most likely, you'll have a template group named "Embeds", "Includes", "Global", "Layouts", or something along those lines. In that template group you will likely have a template named "head" or "header". What we are looking for here is the template that outputs your website's `<head>` tag, which is where your stylesheets' `<link>` tags are going to be. I would edit those tags so they point at a protocol-relative URL instead of a hard coded one. So one example for you would be to convert this tag:

`<link href="http://www.mysite.com/assets/css/style.3.0.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

to this:

`<link href="//www.mysite.com/assets/css/style.3.0.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

This is actually an anti-pattern at this point, but it is probably the best way for you to move forward for now. You'll want to enforce SSL on your site at all times, but that is beyond this answer's scope, and using a protocol-relative URL will work now and after you enforce SSL. After you do enforce SSL, you should change those links to start with `https`, but they will still work with the protocol-relative URL so nothing should break.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will try this and report back if we have been successful. Again, thanks for your time. @jrothafer - sorry  I didn't realize the etiquette regards branding as it's my first time posting.

Comment: @NaomiWalker No sorry necessary; there is no etiquette really here. If you want to leave your branding in your question, please put it back. I removed it out of a concern of advertising a web property that may have existing known vulnerabilities; It was for your protection :)

Comment: Thanks @jrothafer - Nope we'll leave as it is. Much appreciated for your help.